# Conditionally formatting bar styles in Project 2010

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010

In Project 2010, is it possible to conditionally format a bar style/color based on the value of a custom field for a given task?

I see a pretty complicated workaround to accomplish this with Project 2007 here: http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/epm/archive/2009/07/23/formatting-the-gantt-chart-in-ms-project-2007.aspx, but it would be great if there is an easier way to do this in 2010.

Edit: At Perry's request, adding more information about what I am specifically trying to do.

I have a project that has tasks carried out in parallel by different teams.  I have added a custom "Department" field that allows me to specify that a given task belongs to Department Foo, Department Bar, or Department Schmucatelli.

Although I can create views to filter or group the tasks by department, I would like Project to actually color-code my Gantt chart tasks Red (if they belong to Department Foo), Green (if they belong to Department Bar), or Purple (if they belong to department Schmucatelli).

I can do this manually by filtering by department, selecting all, and formatting the bars (once for each department), but I would like this to happen automatically depending on what department I select for a given task.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you. I've tweeted it out, but you might want to put a lot more detail in the question. With detail, if someone is interested they can play around with the problem and find you an answer.

Comment: Additional detail added :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be a question for http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-project, as it's basically asking about a tool *functionality* rather than *usability*? I understand that it MIGHT get more answers @ PMSE as we might have more MS-Project users here, but still...

Comment: Will the VBA solution above work with the calendar view? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: This does not look like an answer to the question. I suggest that it may be more appropriate to put this as a comment to the original question, rather than posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to answer your question (without the need for VB)

http://www.pmconnection.com/modules.php?name=News&file=article&sid=24

I don't have Project 2010 to verify, but the solution shown makes sense and seems to do what you want(??)

Comment: +1. Tested in Project 2010 and works like a charm.

Comment: Awesome!  If you like the answer, you might "mark it as correct" (unless there is a better answer that comes up! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I like the VBA solution above, but it's going to be slooow for large projects.  Using a combination of Custom Flag Fields and Custom Bar Styles is the traditional way to do this.  A tutorial for doing this is shown [here](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s113/conditional_formatting_in_microsoft_project_gantt_charts_part1.htm).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty (what below is just a simple first try) VBA approach could be something like:

```
Sub ColorBars()
' Colors bars according to the value of Text1 field
' Written on Mon 23/05/11 by Bartlomiej Garbacz
  Dim ts As tasks
  Dim t As task
  Dim color

  Set ts = ActiveProject.tasks

  For Each t In ts
    If Not t Is Nothing Then
      If Not t.Summary Then
      ' Excluding summary tasks
        Select Case t.Text1
          Case "Team1"
            color = ColorConstants.vbRed
          Case "Team2"
            color = ColorConstants.vbGreen
          Case "Team3"
            color = ColorConstants.vbBlue
          Case Else
            color = ColorConstants.vbBlack
        End Select

        GanttBarFormatEx TaskID:=t.ID, GanttStyle:=1, StartShape:=0, StartType:=0, StartColor:=0, MiddleShape:=1, MiddlePattern:=1, MiddleColor:=color
      End If
    End If
  Next t
End Sub
```

And when you define a shortcut key for your macro, you can have 'almost automatic' update of your schedule.

To gain access to VBA remember to *Customize the Ribbon* in your MS Project 2010 *Options* and tick the **Developer** tab.